# Comunicar de forma continua dos programas *.exe usando C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un ejecutable graysimage.exe que convierte imágenes a escala de grises y se puede ejecutar desde el cmd de Windows pasándole la ruta de la imagen como argumento.

Ahora después hice otro programa llamado main.exe y desde allí invoco a graysimage.exe usando la función system();

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    system(u8"c:/users/toshiba/desktop/graysimage.exe --c:/users/toshiba/desktop/imag.png");
    
    std::string salida;

    return 0;
}
```

salida:

```
imagen pasada a escala de grises exitosamente
```

como capturo la salida para guardarla en la variable salida. Me gustaría comunicar los dos programas de forma continua y que pueda enviar mensajes el uno al otro para que trabajen juntos en equipo. Solo me interesa lograr esto en la plataforma Windows.

Comment: Si solo quieres recivir la salida de tu programa y colocarla
en un string, puede que te  convenga buscar `_popen`. Si
quieres que se comuniquen varios mensajes puede que quieras
hecharle un vistaso a las bidirecctional pipes.

Comment: Esto de los pipes según lo que he leído suena prometedor pero por desgracia No logro encontrar un buen tutorial que explique a detalle como se usan

Comment: Hola @JosephGen aqui tienes un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/3068427